# Fishpig wordpress integration - Show repeater fields

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

Has anyone managed to get repeater fields to come though? I have a repeater in Wordpress called page_section, when i do the below code

```
<?php $rows = $page->getMetaValue('page_section');?>
<?php var_dump ($rows);?>
```

all i get returned is **string(1) "2"**

Yes - see below for version. When i do the Var_dump i get returned string(1) "2", the documentation says i should get an array returned. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Versions**

- ACF Pro - 5.1.6
- Fishpig Wordpress integration - 3.1.1.21
- Fishpig Add-on Root 1.0.2.2
- Fishpig Add-on ACF - 1.2.5.1

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes, The fishpig extension does not support the PRO version of ACF yet. So you need to de-activate it in your wordpress install and instead use the ACF repeater Add-on. Ben from Fishpig is working on the ACF Pro compatibility so email him so see when it will be released.

Comment: One question David, if you need to modify your functions.php I notice that the changes you do under your theme doesn't take place on magento blog. Do you know if there any other file over writing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array();
$raw_rows = $page->getMetaValue('rows');

foreach($raw_rows as $row):

    echo $row['page_section'];

endforeach;
```

Boop.

Answer (score 0):

The ACF integration extension now supports ACF Pro so if you upgrade the extension to version 1.3.0.0 (just released), the ACF Pro fields should function correctly.